# string replace without using any in-built function

Tags: php, arrays, string, algorithm

With a program to replace substring in a string without using str_replace

should be generic function should work for below example:

1. Word :         Hello world
   Replace word : llo
   Replace by   : zz
   Output should be: Hezz world
2. Word :         Hello world
   Replace word : o
   Replace by   : xx
   Output should be: Hellxx wxxrld

This is what i wrote to solve it

```
function stringreplace($str, $stringtoreplace, $stringreplaceby){
    $i=0;$add='';
    while($str[$i] != ''){
        $add .= $str[$i];
        $j=0;$m=$i;$l=$i;$check=0;
        if($str[$i] == $stringtoreplace[$j]){
            while($stringtoreplace[$j] != ''){
                if($str[$m] == $stringtoreplace[$j]){
                    $check++;
                }
                $j++;$m++;
            }
            if($check == strlen($stringtoreplace)){
                $n=0;$sub='';
                for($n=0;$n<=strlen($stringtoreplace);$n++){    
                $str[$l] = ''; 
                    $sub .= $str[$l];
                    $l++;
                }
                $add .= $stringreplaceby;
                $i += $check;
            }
        }

        $i++;
    }//echo $add;exit;
    return $add;
}
```

I am getting output as helzzworld .
Please take a look what I did wrong or if you have better solution for this please suggest.

Comment: you can try this...  preg_replace():

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: @Learning Do strlen is allowed or not? :D

Comment: it will be good if we don't use that too.

Comment: do you want to solve this without using built in functions like strlen ?

Comment: yes without any inbuilt function

Comment: Can anyone please review my program and let me know where i went wrong please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simplest one, without using `str_replace`, Here we are using `explode` and `implode` and `substr_count`.

> **1.** `substr_count` for counting and checking the existence of substring.
>
> **2.** `explode` for exploding string into array on the basis of matched substring.
>
> **3.** `implode` joining the string with replacement.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/794581)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string="Hello world";
echo strReplace($string,"llo","zz");
echo strReplace($string,"o","xx");
function strReplace($string,$toReplace,$replacement)
{
    if(substr_count($string, $toReplace))
    {
        $array=explode($toReplace,$string);
        return implode($replacement, $array);
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/794623) `not best, but working`

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string="Hello world";
echo strReplace($string,"llo","zz");
echo strReplace($string,"o","xx");
function strReplace($string,$toReplace,$replacement)
{
    while($indexArray=checkSubStringIndexes($toReplace,$string))
    {
        $stringArray=  getChars($string);
        $replaced=false;
        $newString="";
        foreach($stringArray as $key => $value)
        {
            if(!$replaced && in_array($key,$indexArray))
            {
                $newString=$newString.$replacement;
                $replaced=true;
            }
            elseif(!in_array($key,$indexArray))
            {
                $newString=$newString.$value;
            }
        }
        $string=$newString;
    }
    return $string;
}
function getLength($string)
{
    $counter=0;
    while(true)
    {
        if(isset($string[$counter]))
        {
            $counter++;
        }
        else 
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $counter;
}
function getChars($string)
{
    $result=array();
    $counter=0;
    while(true)
    {
        if(isset($string[$counter]))
        {
            $result[]=$string[$counter];
            $counter++;
        }
        else 
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
function checkSubStringIndexes($toReplace,$string)
{
    $counter=0;
    $indexArray=array();
    $newCounter=0;
    $length=  getLength($string);
    $toReplacelength=  getLength($toReplace);
    $mainCharacters= getChars($string);
    $toReplaceCharacters= getChars($toReplace);
    for($x=0;$x<$length;$x++)
    {
        if($mainCharacters[$x]==$toReplaceCharacters[0])
        {
            for($y=0;$y<$toReplacelength;$y++)
            {
                if(isset($mainCharacters[$x+$y]) && $mainCharacters[$x+$y]==$toReplaceCharacters[$y])
                {
                    $indexArray[]=$x+$y;
                    $newCounter++;
                }
            }
            if($newCounter==$toReplacelength)
            {
                return $indexArray;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is really works, but aim of this program is to not use inbuilt function. I know I did used strlen.

Comment: @Learning I have updated a solution, probably not the best but working..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by explode the main string into array then implode your stringreplaceby to  your array parts creating new string

```
 <?php
    function stringreplce($str,$strreplace,$strreplaceby){
        $str_array=explode($strreplace,$str);
        $newstr=implode($strreplaceby,$str_array);
        return $newstr;
    }
    echo stringreplce("Hello World","llo","zz")."<br>";
    echo stringreplce("Hello World","Hel","zz")."<br>";
    echo stringreplce("Hello World"," Wo","zz")."<br>";
    echo stringreplce("Hello World","rl","zz")."<br>";
    echo stringreplce("Hello World","ld","zz")."<br>";
    ?>
```

Comment: ok I understand you but I don't think that you can do it without use of strops or strstr or (implode/explode) you want to remove part of string from your main string this is the main part that need built in function

Answer (score 0):

```
function ganti_kata($kata,$kata_awal,$kata_ganti){
    $i =0; $hasil;
    $panjang = strlen($kata);
    while ($i < $panjang) {
        if ($kata[$i] == $kata_awal) {
            $hasil[$i] = $kata_ganti;
            echo $hasil[$i];
        }
        else if ($kata[$i] !== $kata_awal){
            $hasil[$i] = $kata[$i];
            echo $hasil[$i];
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
echo ganti_kata('Riowaldy Indrawan','a','x');
```

> This code using php